# Implement Catch-all HTTP Server using DNSMASQ

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns, dnsmasq, hostapd

### Ubuntu 14.04 | dnsmasq

My goal is to setup a catch-all HTTP server using an Ubuntu 14.04 workstation as DNS resolver. I have installed dnsmasq on my Ubuntu 14.04 OS using `apt-get install dnsmasq` and I've confirmed it's running using 'service dnsmasq status'.

My goal is to route all traffic on the machine via dnsmasq.
In the configuration file for dnsmasq, I have the following:

```
interface=eth0
interface=wlan0  
address=/#/192.168.1.1
no-resolv server=192.168.1.1
listen-address=192.168.1.1
```

I want a scenario where opening firefox and navigating to *.com/net/org/etc pulls up a locally hosted site on my computer instead of actually having such requests routed through the nameservers configured in `resolv.conf` and processed by the corresponding DNS server(s).

Been at this one for hours. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) I'm sorry and, please, blame it on me: I'm confused and confusing...  But...  *What's your question???* :/  You want all .com/net... sites to resolve to a site that's hosted on your computer?  Like a honeypot?